# For a school project on Python, I need to write a program that allows users to order pizza. The user must be able to order as many pizzas as they want

Tags: python

Is there a way to turn a string into the name of a list so that each list corresponds to a different pizza being ordered? That way, I would not have to individually make lists for all the possible pizzas the user could order.
I was thinking something like this, though I know it is wrong:

```
num_pizzas = 4
list_name = 'pizza'+num_pizzas
list_name = [cheese, pepperoni, onions, pineapple]
```

Theoretically, the name of the list would be the string list_name. In this case, the name of the new list would be pizza4. 
I know that the example I gave just changes the type of the existing variable list_name. The idea is for the new list to correspond with the number of pizzas that are being ordered.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you familiar with dictionaries in Python?

Comment: Daniel Walker: I am now! I'm a beginner, so I did not know about them, but all of the answers I got suggested using them.

Comment: Please start with a tutorial or two and check out the documentation to get an overview of what tools are there. It could be that the thing you need is called "string formatting". Stack Overflow can't teach language basics from scratch or replace research. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, it's unclear what you have and what you want, even more so because you assign to `list_name` and without using the content, overwrite it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using a dict with it you could achieve something like this:

```py
pizza_orders = {
    "pizza1": {
        "num_orders": 2,
        "ingridients": ["ing1", "ing2"]
    },
    "pizza2": {
        "num_orders": 3,
        "ingridients": ["ing2", "ing3"]
    },
}

# to acces ingridents/num_orders
print(pizza_orders['pizza1']['num_orders'])
>>> 2
print(pizza_orders['pizza1']['ingridients'])
>>> ["ing1", "ing2"]
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for helping out :)

Answer (score 1):

Would a dictionary be of use here?
Something like this maybe:

```
ordered_pizzas = {"pizza1":["cheese", "pepperoni", "onions", "pineapple"]}

### to add new
num_pizzas = 2
list_name = 'pizza'+str(num_pizzas)
ordered_pizzas[list_name] = ["cheese", "pepperoni", "olives"]
```

that way you can just access lists by using a string index.

Comment: This is perfect! I'm a beginner, so I did not know about dictionaries. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary maybe and call the pizza type from the stored key value...

```
list_name = {"pizza1":"cheese", "pizza2":"pepperoni", "pizza3":"onions", "pizza4":"pineapple"}

for key in list_name.items():
  print(key)

('pizza1', 'cheese')
('pizza2', 'pepperoni')
('pizza3', 'onions')
('pizza4', 'pineapple')

for key, value in list_name.items():
  print(key, value)

pizza1 cheese
pizza2 pepperoni
pizza3 onions
pizza4 pineapple
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I did not know about dictionaries, but now I know they are very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. I am confused on what you want.

One solution is to use dictionary to associate each pizza toppings with unique pizza name. For example. Python 3+ syntax:

```
def generate_pizza(pizza_num: int, toppings: list) -> dict:
    pizza_name = "pizza" + pizza_num
    return {pizza_name: toppings}
```

Then you would use the code above like

```
toppings = [cheese, pepperoni, onions, pineapple]
list_name = generate_pizza(4, toppings)
```

then your `list_name` will be `{"pizza4": [cheese, pepperoni, onions, pineapple]}`. And you can add more pizzas to that dict.

Comment: Something like that is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a nested list, since you're unable to automatically assign the value of a variable as a variable name. You could use a dictionary as well, but this is another example since you're already using lists.

Try out the following:

```
num_pizzas = 0
allPizza = []
order = input("Would you like to order a pizza? y/n")
while order!="n":
    pizza = []
    topping = input("What do you want on your pizza?")
    pizza.append(topping)
    moreTopping = input("Another topping? y/n")
    while moreTopping != "n":
        topping = input("What do you want on your pizza?")
        pizza.append(topping)
        moreTopping = input("Another topping? y/n")
    allPizza.append(pizza)
    order = input("Would you like to order another pizza? y/n")
num = 0
for i in allPizza:
    print("Pizza" + " " + str(num) + " with", end=' ')
    print(', '.join(allPizza[num]))
    print()
    num+=1
```

Comment: It's a bit less elegant than a dictionary, but still functional.